# feed output of command to another command as file

Tags: bash, files, pipe, io-redirection, cat

I can make config file of `tor` with `cat <<EOF` command as follows :

```
cat <<EOF
SocksPort 9050
ControlPort 9150
DataDirectory /usr/var/lib/tor/torrc
EOF
```

but it can save output with redirect `>` to file. And then use `tor -f file`

But how feed directly to `tor -f` ? I don't want to make file or any kind of temp file and delete afterwards.

- I want something like

  ```
  tor -f < $(cat <<EOF
  ...
  ...
  EOF)
  ```

  but it gives `EOF): ambiguous redirect`
- With direct redirect ? `tor -f <<EOF... not worked`
- And pipeline will give error.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is called process substitution; it's not a standard feature of the shell, but supported in Bash/ksh/zsh. An example:

```
$ echo <(echo foo)
/dev/fd/63
$ cat <(echo foo)
foo
```

The `<(cmd)` expands to the name of a file which the shell arranges to have the output from `cmd` available to read. On Linux, it's likely `/dev/fd/NN`, but it might be a named pipe too, depends on the system and the shell.

So, I suppose you could use

```
tor -f  <(cat <<EOF
...
...
EOF
)
```

Note that above with `cat`, I could have used `cat < <(echo foo)` with the redirection instead of `cat <(echo foo)`, it's the same difference as with `cat < somefile` and `cat somefile`. `cat` works with either, since it reads stdin by default, but if the tool expects a filename, you wouldn't add the redirection.

---

Anyway, the above is a bit hairy, it'd be better to have `tor` read the here-doc directly, without another process in the middle. You'll just have to make it read stdin.

A few utilities read stdin (or write to stdout) if the filename given is `-`, but if `tor` doesn't support that, you can use `/dev/stdin` (resp. `/dev/stdout`), so I suppose this might work:

```
tor -f /dev/stdin <<EOF
...
...
EOF
```

Unless of course it needs stdin for something else. In that case, you can should be able to use another fd with the here-doc:

```
tor -f /dev/fd/9 9<<EOF
...
...
EOF
```

(though you need a system that supports `/dev/fd/NN`)